# Apply function to an array of tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector

**I have a function that I would like to apply to an array of tuples** and I am wondering if there is a clean way to do it.

Normally, I could use `np.vectorize` to apply the function to each item in the array, however, in this case "each item" is a tuple so numpy interprets the array as a 3d array and applies the function to each item **within the tuple**.

So I can assume that the incoming array is one of:

1. tuple
2. 1 dimensional array of tuples
3. 2 dimensional array of tuples

I can probably write some looping logic but it seems like `numpy` most likely has something that does this more efficiently and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

This is an example.  I am trying to apply the `tuple_converter` function to each tuple in the array.

```
array_of_tuples1 = np.array([
        [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(5,6,7)],
        [(7,2,3),(2,6,4),(5,6,6)],
        [(8,2,3),(2,5,4),(7,6,7)],
    ])

array_of_tuples2 = np.array([
        (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(5,6,7),
    ])

plain_tuple = (1,2,3)



# Convert each set of tuples
def tuple_converter(tup):
    return tup[0]**2 + tup[1] + tup[2]

# Vectorizing applies the formula to each integer rather than each tuple
tuple_converter_vectorized = np.vectorize(tuple_converter)

print(tuple_converter_vectorized(array_of_tuples1))
print(tuple_converter_vectorized(array_of_tuples2))
print(tuple_converter_vectorized(plain_tuple))
```

Desired Output for `array_of_tuples1`:

```
[[ 6 11 38]
 [54 14 37]
 [69 13 62]]
```

Desired Output for `array_of_tuples2`:

```
[ 6 11 38]
```

Desired Output for `plain_tuple`:

```
6
```

But the code above produces this error *(because it is trying to apply the function to an integer rather than a tuple.)*

```
<ipython-input-209-fdf78c6f4b13> in tuple_converter(tup)
     10 
     11 def tuple_converter(tup):
---> 12     return tup[0]**2 + tup[1] + tup[2]
     13 
     14 

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: A little "X-Y" problem going on here- could you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Good call, I will add it to the example

Comment: Should the first row of the desired output for the 1st and 2nd cases be `[6 11, 38]` (and the other rows would then be different too)? You want the function to map per tuple, right? Not across tuples?

Comment: Yes, I messed that up and I am working on fixing it now.  Sorry to confuse :/

Comment: No problem, take your time, just wanted to be clear :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*array_of_tuples1* and *array_of_tuples2* are not actually arrays of tuples, but just 3- and 2-dimensional arrays of integers:

```
In [1]: array_of_tuples1 = np.array([
   ...:         [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(5,6,7)],
   ...:         [(7,2,3),(2,6,4),(5,6,6)],
   ...:         [(8,2,3),(2,5,4),(7,6,7)],
   ...:     ])

In [2]: array_of_tuples1
Out[2]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7]],

       [[7, 2, 3],
        [2, 6, 4],
        [5, 6, 6]],

       [[8, 2, 3],
        [2, 5, 4],
        [7, 6, 7]]])
```

So, instead of vectorizing your function, because it then will basically for-loop through the elements of the array (integers), you should [apply it on the suitable axis](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) (the axis of the "tuples") and not care about the type of the sequence:

```
In [6]: np.apply_along_axis(tuple_converter, 2, array_of_tuples1)
Out[6]: 
array([[ 6, 11, 38],
       [54, 14, 37],
       [69, 13, 62]])

In [9]: np.apply_along_axis(tuple_converter, 1, array_of_tuples2)
Out[9]: array([ 6, 11, 38])
```

Comment: This is great.  I even looked at this function in the docs and had decided it wasn't what I needed.  Always great to get a second opinion ;)

Answer (score 3):

The other answer above is certainly correct, and probably what you're looking for. But I noticed you put the word "clean" into your question, and so I'd like to add this answer as well.

If we can make the assumption that all the tuples are `3` element tuples (or that they have some constant number of elements), then there's a nice little trick you can do so that the same piece of code will work on any single tuple, 1d array of tuples, or 2d array of tuples without an if/else for the 1d/2d cases. I'd argue that avoiding switches is always cleaner (although I suppose this could be contested).

```
import numpy as np

def map_to_tuples(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    flattened = x.flatten().reshape(-1, 3)
    return np.array([tup[0]**2 + tup[1] + tup[2] for tup in flattened]).reshape(x.shape[:-1])
```

Outputs the following for your inputs (respectively), as desired:

```
[[ 6 11 38]
 [54 14 37]
 [69 13 62]]

[ 6 11 38]

6
```

Comment: That's an interesting way to go about it. It'd be possible to use `apply_along_axis()` in the same fashion too, I think. Wrap the input in an array as you do and apply along last axis (0 for plain tuple input).

Comment: Haha indeed! I'll do anything to avoid a switch statement :P

Answer (score 1):

If you are serious about the `tuples` bit, you could define a structured dtype.

```
In [535]: dt=np.dtype('int,int,int')

In [536]: x1 = np.array([
        [(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(5,6,7)],
        [(7,2,3),(2,6,4),(5,6,6)],
        [(8,2,3),(2,5,4),(7,6,7)],
    ], dtype=dt)

In [537]: x1
Out[537]: 
array([[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7)],
       [(7, 2, 3), (2, 6, 4), (5, 6, 6)],
       [(8, 2, 3), (2, 5, 4), (7, 6, 7)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Note that the display uses tuples.  `x1` is a 3x3 array of type `dt`.  The elements, or records, are displayed as tuples.  This more useful if the tuple elements differ - float, integer, string etc.

Now define a function that works with fields of such an array:

```
In [538]: def foo(tup):
    return tup['f0']**2 + tup['f1'] + tup['f2']
```

It applies neatly to `x1`.

```
In [539]: foo(x1)
Out[539]: 
array([[ 6, 11, 38],
       [54, 14, 37],
       [69, 13, 62]])
```

It also applies to a 1d array of the same dtype.

```
In [540]: x2=np.array([(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(5,6,7) ],dtype=dt)

In [541]: foo(x2)
Out[541]: array([ 6, 11, 38])
```

And a 0d array of matching type:

```
In [542]: foo(np.array(plain_tuple,dtype=dt))
Out[542]: 6
```

But `foo(plain_tuple)` won't work, since the function is written to work with named fields, not indexed ones.

The function could be modified to cast the input to the correct dtype if needed:

```
In [545]: def foo1(tup):
    temp = np.asarray(tup, dtype=dt)
   .....:     return temp['f0']**2 + temp['f1'] + temp['f2']

In [548]: plain_tuple
Out[548]: (1, 2, 3)

In [549]: foo1(plain_tuple) 
Out[549]: 6

In [554]: foo1([(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(5,6,7)])  # list of tuples
Out[554]: array([ 6, 11, 38])
```